# need a quick argument for proving ideal non equality

Tags: ring-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Is there a quick way to argue that $(7) \not\subset (3,x^2+1)$ ? where $(7)$ is ideal generated by $7$ and $(3,x^2+1)$ is ideal generated by $3$ and $x^2+1$ (all ideals are in $\mathbb{Z}[x])$

Comment: yes, now Edited...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction $(7) \subset (3, x^2+1)$. Then we would have $1 = 7 - 2 \cdot 3 \in (3, x^2+1)$, so that $(3, x^2+1)$ would be the whole ring. But now
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^2+1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+1)$$
is not trivial (it has 9 elements), so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$ 7 \,=\, 3f(x)+(x^2\!+1)g(x)\,\overset{\large x\,=\,i}\Rightarrow\, 7 = 3 f(i)\,\overset{\rm Norm}\Rightarrow\, 49 = 9 f(i)\overline{f(i)}\,\Rightarrow\, 49/9\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$